# I want to update multiple values ​associated with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, nuxt.js

## What I want to come true

I want to update multiple values ​​that are related in Rails.
Send an update request from JavaScript and update the data in Rails.
There was no problem at the time of create, but I can not update.

#Code

*JavaScript**

```js
export const actions = {
  // Post the book selected by the user
  post (context) {
    const list = context.state.todos.list
    const selectedBook = context.state.book.selectedBook

    // Send to array
    const postItemsAttributes =
      list.map((item) => {
        return {
          content: item.content,
          status: item.status
        }
      })

    // plugin/bookInfo  $title,$author,$image
    this.$axios.$post(url.POST_API + 'posts', {
      post: {
        title: this.$title(selectedBook),
        author: this.$author(selectedBook),
        image: this.$image(selectedBook),
        post_items_attributes: postItemsAttributes
      }
    })
      .then((responseBook) => {
        context.commit('book/userBook', responseBook)
        context.commit('book/clearBook')
        context.commit('todos/clear')
      })
  },

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Value cannot be updated
  update (context) {
    const list = context.state.todos.list
    const bookId = context.state.book.selectedBook.id
    const content =
    list.map((item) => {
      return {
        content: item.content,
        status: false
      }
    })
    this.$axios.$patch(url.POST_API + 'posts/' + bookId, {
      post: {
        post_items_attributes: content
      }
    })
  }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}
```

**Rails**
controller

```rb
class Api::V1::PostsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        posts = Post.new(post_params)
        if posts.save
            render json: "OK", status: 200
        else
            render json: "EEEOR", status: 500
        end
    end

     def update
        post = Post.find(params[:id])
        post.post_items.update(content_params)
     end
     


        private
              # update
            def content_params
                params.require(:post).permit(post_items_attributes:[:id, :content, :status])
            end
            #create
         def post_params
                params.require(:post).permit(:title, :author, :image, post_items_attributes: [:id, :content, :status])
         end
end
```

model/post

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :post_items, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_items, allow_destroy: true

    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :author, presence: true
    validates :image, presence: true
end
```

model/post_item

```
class PostItem < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :post

end
```

## Error

```
api_1    | Started PATCH "/api/v1/posts/16" for 172.29.0.1 at 2021-09-06 22:15:10 +0900
api_1    | Processing by Api::V1::PostsController#update as HTML
api_1    |   Parameters: {"post"=>{"post_items_attributes"=>[{"content"=>"Test", "status"=>false}]}, "id"=>"16"}
api_1    |   Post Load (13.0ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
api_1    |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb:23:in `update'
api_1    |   PostItem Load (15.4ms)  SELECT "post_items".* FROM "post_items" WHERE "post_items"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 16]]
api_1    |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb:24:in `update'
api_1    | Completed 204 No Content in 49ms (ActiveRecord: 29.5ms | Allocations: 1576)
```

## What I tried myself

①　I tried using post_all, but it didn't work because post_all is used directly in the model.

Comment: Try to find out if it's a Nuxt or a Rails issue. For that, try the Rails method directly on the backend app itself. Then if it works, try to debug what you're sending with Nuxt.

Comment: in the controller#update method, it should be `post.update(content_params)` b/c the model `Post` has a method `post_items_attributes=` created by the (presumed) `accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_items` (you do have that don't you?).  Then you need to render and return something to the browser (you're not returning anything, that's why you see `No Content` in the log.

Comment: In addition to @LesNightingill's excellent suggestions you actually need to check if creating and updating records is successful and return the correct responses. Prepare to be very disappointed if you assume that the client will always send valid input.

Comment: @ Les Nightingill 　Yes I'm using ``accepts_nested_attributes_for``.Sure enough, the status is now 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of nested attributes is that you update the children through the parent:

```rb
module Api 
  module V1
    class PostsController < ApplicationController

      # POST /api/v1/posts
      def create
        post = Post.new(create_params)
        if post.save
          render json: post, status: :created,
          location: [:api, :v1, post]
        else
          render json: { errors: post.errors.full_messages },
          status: :unprocessable_entity # not 500 - Internal Server Error!
        end
      end

      # PATCH /api/v1/posts/1
      def update
        if post.update(update_params)
          head :ok 
          # you can also return the updated record
          # this is useful if you have any server side transformations 
          # to the record 
          # render json: post, status: :ok
        else
          render json: { errors: post.errors.full_messages },
          status: :unprocessable_entity 
        end
      end
      
      private
      # just a memoizing convenience method to keep it DRY
      def post 
        @post ||= Post.find(params[:id])
      end 
      
      # if you need to separate the whitelists for updating and creating 
      # use names which don't require comments 
      def update_params
        params.require(:post)
        .permit(
          post_items_attributes: post_item_params
        )
      end

      def create_params
        params.require(:post)
        .permit(
          :title, :author, :image, 
          post_items_attributes: post_item_params
        )
      end
      
      def post_item_params
        [:id, :content, :status]
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

Note that `render json: "OK"` is an anti-pattern. Return meaningful JSON which the client can actually use or don't return any at all (just the headers). Use the semantically correct HTTP status codes to tell the client if the operation is successful or not.

If you want to update a post item individually you would create a separate `PATCH /api/v1/post_items/:id` route.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the dry and Json response. I am getting the error when I use the parameter  for ``post_items_attributes: post_item_params`` as you suggested. ``ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'post_items_attributes' for PostItem.):``

Comment: Thats strange - do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_items_attributes` in `Post`?

Comment: I've already set up accepts_nested_attributes_for in the Rails model, and it works fine for create, but only update doesn't work.Edit the question text to add all the codes.

Comment: The error does not make any sense. Did you actually use the code in the answer? Its clearly passing the input to an instance of Post and not PostItem like in your question. The only explaination I can think of is that you are running the wrong code.

Comment: We have copied the values and used them. The error is gone and it can now be saved. Thank you very much.